# Pre-populating paypal customer information

Tags: php, paypal

I'm building a checkout page, where the user fills in the details - name, surname, address etc.

Now how do I get the information from my checkout FORM to the paypals checkout summary?

How do I add information to these fields that Paypal requires in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="{$_POST['name']}">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="{$_POST['surname']}">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{$_POST['phone']}">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="{$_POST['address']}">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="{$_POST['city']}">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="{$_POST['region']}">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="{$_POST['pindex']}">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="{$_POST['country']}">
```

As you can see, I tried with the POST variable, but this is not working. Do I need to create another page, where the buyer confirms the information? Because then the POST variables would be SET before the buyer presses PAY NOW button.

Answer (score 0):

These are the correct variables that you would be using.  Make sure that you pass over all of the variables that would be included in the address section, even if you are not populating them.  Check out this [page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU).  Such as "address2" and etc., you can pass a blank value.  I have seen this in the pass where if not all variables where passed, it would not prepopulate.